# Rails 5.1.: strong params for JSON POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have JS where data are posted with Ajax and in terminal my params look like this:

```
Started POST "/strongbolt/user_groups" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-06-27 16:27:23 +0000
Processing by Strongbolt::UserGroupsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"strongbolt_user_group"=>{"name"=>"Some test group",
 "description"=>"Some test description", "user_ids"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3"},
 "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"5"}}, "role_ids"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1"},
 "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}}}}
```

My Create action looks like this:

```
  def create
    user_roles #Helper method
    @user_group = Strongbolt::UserGroup.create!(user_group_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { flash.now[:notice] = "User group #{@user_group.name} created!" }
        format.json { render json: {
          data: @user_group.as_json(only: [:id, :name, :description], include: {
            users: { only: [:id, :name] }, roles: {only: [:id, :name] }}),
          }
        }
    end
  end

  private

  def user_group_params
    params.require(:strongbolt_user_group)
          .permit(:name, :description, {user_ids: []}, {role_ids: []})
  end
```

In my terminal I can see it create `name` and `description`, but does not insert `user_ids` and `role_ids`. So far I've been trying differently with params, but no luck - can't make them to be saved.
I get this error: `Unpermitted parameters: :user_ids, :role_ids`

**How do I make all params to be saved, please? Thank you!**

Comment: Have you tried without curly braces wrapping user_ids and role_ids? I haven't tested, but I'm almost sure that's the cause

Comment: @Aleksandrus Thank you, however this does not work as it still says `Unpermitted parameters: :user_ids, :role_ids`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
{
  "strongbolt_user_group"=>{
    "name"=>"Some test group",
    "description"=>"Some test description",
    "user_ids"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"5"}}, 
    "role_ids"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}}
  }
}
```

you should send

```
{
  "strongbolt_user_group"=>{
    "name"=>"Some test group",
    "description"=>"Some test description",
    "user_ids"=>["3", "2", "5"], 
    "role_ids"=>["1", "2"]
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you can't change the format of received params, you could do something like the following:

```
private

def user_group_params
  modified_params.require(:strongbolt_user_group)
        .permit(:name, :description, {user_ids: []}, {role_ids: []})
end

def modified_params
  user_ids = params[:strongbolt_user_group][:user_ids].values.map(&:values).flatten
  role_ids = params[:strongbolt_user_group][:role_ids].values.map(&:values).flatten
  ActionController::Parameters.new({
    strongbolt_user_group: params[:strongbolt_user_group].except(:user_ids, role_ids).merge(user_ids: user_ids, role_ids: role_ids)
  })
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I know I should be sending that way. It's just my JS sends params as mentioned above... not sure if I can change that. Can I do something about it on Rails side?

Comment: ideally you should send it in the correct format, but you could modify the params i.e `params["strongbolt_user_group"]["user_ids"].map {|k, v| v.values}.flatten` would return `["3", "2", "5"]`

Comment: Where do I place that in my code? I tried that as `before_action` but got this `NoMethodError (undefined method map for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f1bc9f93df0>`

Comment: Thank you, however it gives me same error as `undefined method map`

Comment: hmm `Method map is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1`... I have updated my answer

Comment: Ok, now it gives me `NoMethodError (private method "require" called for #<Hash:0x007f9e1b5e2098>):`

Comment: yeah, you need a `ActionController::Parameters` object instead of `hash` to use the `require` public method... I've updated it again ;)

Comment: Thank you, now it works :) A lot of work, actually. Rails community the best! Do you have any idea where I could read, how to change format in JS side, please? I assume it can be needed in my project in future.

Comment: I'm glad it's working :) yeah, I recommend sending the params in the correct shape, but it depends on your ajax request...I suggest opening a new question with your ajax request (JS code) ;)